# Error including Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install.php in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am running a Magento store and it shows a white screen when I try to open it in a browser. I checked the logs and the message in there is:

> Warning: include(Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory  in
>   /html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]:
>   Failed opening 'Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php/lib/php:/usr/local/php/lib/php/PEAR')
>   in /html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93

I changed the index.php to show errors and the error shown is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install' not found
>   in /html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 16045

So I went to *app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router* to see if Install.php is there and it is. So why does it not find it?

Thanks!

Comment: this is a result of compiler issues, or a bad XML causing module load problems, or core config files being wrong. If this happens after a module is added, remove the module and review its configurations. If this happens spontaneously, check that it wasn't updates that broke something, and then review the configs for the core system and paths

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error after applying a security patch, but since my shop was already running, I have no need of the Install module router, so I opened up the **app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml** and commented out the lines that are adding this Router.
default -> web -> routers and stores -> default -> web -> routers

`<!--<default>
        <web>
            <routers>
                <install>
                    <area>frontend</area>
                    <class>Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install</class>
                </install>
            </routers>
        </web>
    </default> -->
   <!-- <stores>
         <default>
            <web>
                <routers>
                    <install>
                        <area>frontend</area>
                        <class>Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install</class>
                    </install>
                </routers>
            </web>
        </default>
    </stores> -->`

Comment: This solves the fatal error for me (after manually clearing all sessions & cache, and disabling opcache) **but** the patch adds that router in order to close a security hole. This basically unpatches your Magento install. I want to know why the file isn't autoloading to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to recompile:

In your Magento rootfolder:

```
$ php shell/compiler.php disable
$ php shell/compiler.php clear
$ php shell/compiler.php compile
$ php shell/compiler.php enable
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Re run the compiler script as suggest @Royw (also in backend menu System > Tools > Compiler) or even better deactivate completely as it is totally useless and provide more problems than solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you get these errors, there is another way to disable the compiler. Find the file config.php in the directory includes. It will look like this:
<?php ...
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
comment out both lines like this:
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
try again. You will probably be able to login now. Go to your tools, rerun compilation process and when you get a success, go back to your includes/config.php file and uncomment the lines again.
```

You should find everything working again.